# Material doesnt rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine

In my scene I have two materials (Wood.Dark and Copper.Dark) with `Image Texture` node. They appear in `Material Preview` mode, but doesnt rendering in Cycles. I did check up `View Layer -> Override` property and read all similar question. Nothing help. Disgusting bright rose. [Link to scene .zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fq22kviJUGouQotUWSdokC9j26QjXkg7/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Downloaded file has broken links (as expected) go to File > External > Find Missing will fix all paths ... than it works for me. Seeing texture in material preview can be some cache was used ...

Comment: @vklidu thank you very much! Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file links have broken. Use *File > External Data > Find Missing Files* to refresh them:

[image]